# Post path must match exactly with RKResponseDescriptor pathPattern

Tags: ios, json, url, restkit

So the current service I'm using for updating an object follows the formatting of the following URL

http://www.baseurl.com/servicemethodAddObject/transactionId?clientTime=clientTime

So this is the code I put in there. Roughly.

```
[objectManager addResponseDescriptor:[RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:eventResponseMapping method:RKRequestMethodGET pathPattern:@"/GetStuff" keyPath:nil statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)]];

// I'd want to add items to the URL but the parameters parameter only goes in to the post body, If I add objects to the path @"?GetStuff/?parm=Stuff&parm2=stuff2" then the response will not be mapped properly
[objectManager postObject:object path:@"/GetStuff" parameters:parms success:nil failure:nil];
```

It seems that RestKit requires that the path used to post the object and the pathPattern used to create the RKDescriptor must be an exact match. Is there a way to get restKit to do a comparison that ignores the url parameters for it's object mapping?

Is this even the right thing to do? Posting an object and adding items in the URL.

Answer (score 1):

You can build the path to add your parameters. Using `pathPattern:@"/GetStuff"` will match against built paths like:

```
@"/GetStuff?parm=Stuff&parm2=stuff2"
```

(you will have issues if you add or remove `/` characters that aren't in your path pattern)

Comment: I'd have to add and remove the descriptors since the url is always changing, that and it seems like a giant hack. Is there away to have the path pattern identify that some items will be dynamic? I don't think you can't add regex in the path pattern but that'd work. I posted on the rest kit github and their solution is to NOT add url parameters when posting.

Comment: Ideally you wouldn't use query params, no. The path pattern can take params, check out the spec https://github.com/NimbusKit/sockit but that is not for query params, it's for path segments

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/issues/1877

Apparently the solution is to not do it.